# Word for feeling that an event has been happening for a long time, but has actually happened recently

Tags: single-word-requests

Context for this is in a new relationship when you spend a lot of time with your partner, but have only dated for a few weeks. It feels like you've known them a long time, but at the same time your life was much different a month ago.

I was wondering if there was an obscure word out there that has been used to describe this feeling.

Comment: Since you've tagged this as a single word request, you should include a sample sentence demonstrating how the word would be used.

Comment: Welcome! The request for the sample sentence will let people zero in on what kind of part of speech and connotation you're thinking of.

Comment: This is often called the "[recency illusion](https://www.google.com/search?q=recency+illusion)". The original use was for words, but it generalizes to any frequently-performed experience.